# Two abelian groups with the same order are isomorphic?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

True of false: if G and H are two groups with the same order and both
are abelian, then they are isomorphic.

Comment: Think of $\mathbb{Z}_4$ and the direct sum of two copies of $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: don't forget to explain your answer when you submit your homework. Giving the right answer without explanation does not count for much.

Answer (score 5):

False.

$\mathbb{Z_4}$ and $\mathbb{Z_2}\times\mathbb{Z_2}$ have order $4$ but not isomorphic

Answer (score 1):

Only if the order is square-free.

Comment: a bit more explanation would be helpful.